# How to install .vsix extention file in Visual Studio on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, visual-studio

I just downloaded a VSIX file from the Visual Studio Gallery and i want install [this extention (jQuery snippets)](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/577b9c03-71fb-417b-bcbb-94b6d3d326b8) on Mac.

How to do this?

Comment: I don't know about the Pro or Enterprise versions, but *Community* version of Visual Studio for Mac does not appear to support .vsix files. There is an "Extension Manager..." in "Visual Studio Community" menu, and in lower left corner of Extension Manager window is "Install from file...", but I tried loading a .vsix file downloaded from internet, and it did not recognize it as a valid extension file.

Comment: If OP is still around, would be great if they'd accept the other answer to this question

Comment: One thing worth checking out is suffixing the file with .zip, as in `my_extension.vsix --> my_extension.vsix.zip` and then uncompressing the zip file. Check out the contents. One extension I was trying to setup had a bunch of dll files in it, which is a no starter for MacOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because there's no Visual Studio on Mac OS. And if you're talking about [Visual Studio *Code*](https://code.visualstudio.com/) then it's not compatible with the *.VSIX extensions because it's an entirely different product.

Comment: Microsoft products... Ok, my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: There is now Visual Studio for Mac

Answer (score 5):

Just to update this with the current status, as things have changed in the last year.

VSC have (somewhat) support for vsix: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/publish-extension#_visual-studio-code-compatibility

And Microsoft is working on a Visual Studio for Mac: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/

Comment: VS for Mac has been released

Comment: Regardless of the name, VS on Mac doesn't appear to support .vsix files - at least the *Community* version doesn't recognize a .vsix as a valid extension.  Have not tried Pro or Enterprise on Mac. Also see [Is 'Visual Studio for Mac' Really Visual Studio?](https://adtmag.com/articles/2017/05/10/vs-for-mac.aspx).

Comment: VS on Mac is basically a rebranded Xamarin studio

Comment: Doesn't seem to be recognized for Visual Studio for Mac Community edition version 7.8.4. When I go to menu `Visual Studio > Extensions... > Install from file...` The file selector filter `Extension packages` doesn't display vsix files. And when I change the filter to `All files` selecting my `DgmlPowerTools2017.vsix` doesn't seem to have any effect.