# How to install VSIX files in Visual Studio 2019 on a Machintosh?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, visual-studio

I would like to install [this VSIX file](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=1TheNikita.drpcvs2019) and I'm using a Mojave Mac on version 10.14.6. The Visual Studio version is 8.10.11 (build 8).

How ?

Comment: Hello, why is this tagged with Discord? Also, this website is about asking for specific problems, not to link you to tutorials of installing stuff that are easily googlable. DId you try any? Did you encounter any problems?

Comment: Also, dup that I can't use as close reason now that I've chosen another one: https://superuser.com/questions/990278/how-to-install-vsix-extention-file-in-visual-studio-on-mac

Comment: @Destroy666 - That [duplicate's](https://superuser.com/questions/990278/how-to-install-vsix-extention-file-in-visual-studio-on-mac) answer isn't accurate.  Visual Studio 2022 does exist for MacOS

Comment: @Ramhound there are few answers, more up-to-date ones.

Comment: @Destroy666 - None of those answers are applicable to this question. Every answer is about Visual Studio Code not Visual Studio 2019 (8.10.11 is VS2019). If the author is actually using Visual Studio Code then the question should be clarified.  The appropriate tags should also be used.

Comment: Oh, you're right, reported them as not answers in that case

Comment: What the author wants is not possible.  Visual Studio 2019 (Windows) and Visual Studio 2019 (macOS) are built on two different engines.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825177/installing-extensions-on-visual-studio-2017-mac) SO question as an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible. Answer adapted from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825177/installing-extensions-on-visual-studio-2017-mac

Visual Studio for Mac shares only its name with Visual Studio (for Windows), and is not at all the same code or architecture or... Plugins written for Visual Studio for Windows, .vsix files, cannot be used in Visual Studio for Mac.

Visual Studio for Mac has its own extension marketplace which can be found in the Extensions menu item.

However, [Visual Studio for Mac is being retired in August of 2024](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/mac/migrate-extensions?view=vsmac-2019) (the year I'm posting this answer) and its extension marketplace is going away too. Microsoft suggests that you migrate any code projects you currently have in Visual Studio for Mac to VS Code, which is truly cross-platform, and which will allow you to use that product's full app marketplace.